# q analogue of a number is a polynomial in $[2]_q$

Tags: combinatorics, quantum-groups, q-analogs

$[m]_q = \frac{q^m−q^{-m}}{q-q^{-1}}$ is the q- analogue of the number $m\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$.

$[0]_q=0$, $[1]_q=1$ and $[2]_q=q+q^{-1}$.

I don't know how to prove

- Every $[m]_q$ can be expressed as polynomial in $[2]_q$.

Indeed this is the case.  $[3]_q=[2]^2_q-1$ and $[4]_q=[2]^3_q-2[2]_q$.

I don't know how to prove this in general.

Any reference to study the properties of q- analogue of the number will also be helpful.

Comment: Rather, it's *a* $q$-analogue. Usually, we denote $[m]_q=\frac{q^m-1}{q-1}$. In that notation, your expression is actually $[m]_{q^2}/q^{m-1}$. However, let's use your notation in the rest of this. To prove that $[m]_q$ is a polynomial in $[2]_q$, use induction and note that $$q^m-q^{-m}=\left(q+q^{-1}\right)\left(q^{m-1}-q^{-(m-1)}\right)-\left(q^{m-2}-q^{-(m-2)}\right).$$ Dividing this through by $q-q^{-1}$ yields, in your notation, $[m]_q=[2]_q[m-1]_q-[m-2]_q$. As far as references, let $q=e^{i\theta}$ and read about Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind $U_m$, then $[m]_q=U_m([2]_q/2)$.